# "Saber" in the sense of "to taste:" how should it be conjugated in first person?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, formas-irregulares

### English

Imagine you are a mouse in a cartoon, and you want to tell a cat "I don't taste good!"

It's clear how to conjugate "**saber**" when used in the sense of "**to taste**"   - in *third* or *second* person:

- **It tastes** good = "**Sabe** bien" (or "Sabe rico".)
- **You taste** good = "**Sabes** rico",  etc.

But what about *first person*?

**I taste** good = ?

- "**Sé** bien" --- the same way as all other senses of the word?
- "**Sepo** bien" --- like the similar verb "caber", which is conjugated "quepo"?
- "**Sabo** bien" --- as if the first person present tense of saber were not irregular?

Sé seems like it would be the obvious correct choice, but it sounds odd to me, and also to native speakers to whom I've posed this question.  I'm very interested in opinions on the matter - both whether the other two might be correct, as well as which sounds better... or perhaps at least which sounds *less* strange.

---

### Español

Imagínate que fueras un ratón en una caricatura, y quieres decirle a un gato que no tienes buen sabor.

Es fácil conjugar el verbo “saber” con el sentido de “tener sabor” en *segunda* o *tercera* persona:

- “**Sabe** bien”  o  “Sabe a pollo”.
- “**Sabes** bien” o “Sabes a pollo”.

Pero como lo hacemos en *primera* persona?

- "Sé bien" --- como normalmente se hace con “saber”?
- "Sepo bien" --- igual al verbo similar "caber" que se conjuga "quepo"?
- "Sabo bien" --- como si el verbo no fuera irregular en primera persona?

Parece que la respuesta debería ser clara, que “Sé” seria la forma correcta, pero suena extraño – no solo a mí sino  también a algunos hispanohablantes nativos.  Me interesa mucho escuchar sus opiniones en si posiblemente las otras opciones podrían ser correctos, y también cual opción les suena mejor.

Gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Saber:**

> Este verbo se conjuga del mismo modo en todas sus acepciones, de manera que, con el sentido de ‘tener sabor a alguna cosa’, la primera persona del presente de indicativo es sé (y no sepo); **así pues, se dirá Sé a sal (‘tengo sabor salado’)** de igual forma que se dice Sé matemáticas (‘tengo conocimientos matemáticos’). Esta forma de primera persona del singular del presente de indicativo debe escribirse con tilde, para distinguirla del pronombre átono se

Fuente [RAE - DPD 1.ª edición, 2.ª tirada - Real Academia Española)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=saber)

No he oído *sabo*, sin embargo *sepo* sí aunque lo correcto es *sé*.

Comment: Excelente!  Lo buscaba en la RAE pero no lo encontré.  Me enseñas por favor cuales terminos usaste en la busqueda en [lema.rae.es/drae](http://lema.rae.es/drae)?  Asi me ayudaras a mejorar mis tecnicas investigativas :)

Comment: Busco por el Sr. Google combinaciones como "RAE saber", "DPD saber". Por cierto, en el menú lateral de la web que buscas hay la opción "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas"  y este redirige a lema.rae.es/dpd, allí si pones saber sale.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the correct is the first one, it conjugates as "saber=to know"; though it sounds a little odd. Some alternatives for *"I don't taste good"*

```
"No tengo buen sabor" 

"No soy/estoy sabroso" (o "rico")
```

BTW: in some places (as here, Argentina) the word "saber" with that meaning ("taste") is less used than the above alternatives, in general. Also, coloquially, we use "gusto" as synonym of "sabor": ("No tiene buen gusto"). But it could be confusing to use it here, with an animated /personal subject, because then it would be understood as the analogous in English.

```
"El agua tiene mal gusto" = The water tastes bad.

"Mi hermano tiene mal gusto (para la música)" = My brother has bad taste (for music).
```

Comment: I agree, I would generally use "No soy sabrosa" or the other, but I was curious about the conjugation.  Thanks!